# change text color of singel item in arrayAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-arrayadapter

> > 

I have a TextInputLayout with an AutoCompleteTextView in it

I learned from materials prencebels that the style :

```
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

and using it instead of the spinner to show dropped dawn menu
with ArrayAdapter

**so my problem is I want to change the textColor of each item in the list according to the position**

[image]

I want to turn Oil to red and water to green?

this is my layout :

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:id="@+id/type_Field"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/type1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="Type">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/type_auto_txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.type}"
                    />
```

and the item layout :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/dropped_item"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
/>
```

some code to initiate the adapter with the list:

```
val types=resources.getStringArray(R.array.types)
    val typeAdapter=ArrayAdapter(requireContext(),R.layout.drop_dwon_item,types)
    binding.typeAutoTxt.setAdapter(typeAdapter)
```

I trayed to change the adapter with the fallowing :

1-

```
val arradapter=object : ArrayAdapter<String?>(requireContext(),R.layout.drop_dwon_item,types){
        override fun getDropDownView(
            position: Int,
            convertView: View?,
            parent: ViewGroup
        ): View? {

            val item: View =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent)
            if (item is AutoCompleteTextView){
                if (item.text.equals("Oil")){
                    item.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                }
            }
            
            return item

        }
    }
    binding.typeAutoTxt.setAdapter(arradapter)
```

and also
2-

```
val arradapter=object : ArrayAdapter<String?>(requireContext(),R.layout.drop_dwon_item,types){
override fun getDropDownView(
    position: Int,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup
): View? {
    var v: View? =convertView
    val inflater=context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.drop_dwon_item,null)

    val tv: TextView =v.findViewById(R.id.dropped_item)
    when(position){
        0-> tv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        1-> tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
    }

    return v
}
```

}
binding.typeAutoTxt.setAdapter(arradapter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getView` in your custom adapter, not `getDropDownView`, and the view is actually a `MaterialTextView` but you can just check for `TextView` to be on the safe side:

```kotlin
    // This can also be an array in your resources file or moved to companion object
    private val colors = listOf(Color.RED, Color.GREEN)

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        if (view is TextView) {
            view.setTextColor(colors[position])
        }
        return view
    }
```

And if you want to change the color of the text of the chosen item, you can call `setOnItemClickListener` on the `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```kotlin
    binding.typeAutoTxt.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        binding.typeAutoTxt.setTextColor(colors[position])
    }
```